# How to make picture unzooms normal?

Tags: html, css

I want to make Tribute Page but I have problem with main picture on my website. I added picture with id="image" and when I want to unzoom whole website, picture changes dimensions and it looks awful.

There is my css of #image:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:100%;
height:500px;
border-bottom:black solid 2px;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you will find a solution by not using a relative `width` property. currently it is set to `100%` so when the container in which it is in is changing size it is affected by it. Try an absolute value like `500px` to see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. In the begining of my CSS code was defined box-sizing:border-box, margin:0 and padding:0 for all elements. That was making a problem.